# X-Bench and Trados Studios

Tags: translation

I have a question about using X-Bench in Trados Studios 2011. What happens is that, when you are in X-Bench and you click on 'Edit source' to go to a segment, in the older versions of Trados the file which contains that segment opens, and you can go immediately to that specific segment. When you use X-Bench with Studios, however, X-Bench only opens the file, without going to the segment which has to be corrected. Is there a way to go immediately to that segment without having to type it in the search field, or is that the only way possible?

Many thanks in advance,

Bart

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no possible way do that. But you can do is to search the segment by ID, in Trados press CRTL+G and type the segment number. You will find the segment number for every error in Xbench.

Comment: Xbench released the plugin for Studio 2014 and this is now possible.

Answer (score 0):

For Trados Studio 2014, there is an ApSIC Xbench 3.0 plugin in beta that allows you to go right to the segment selected with **Edit Source**.  You can find more information on how to install the beta plugin [here](http://www.apsic.com/blog/?p=59).